# Manager is assigning pointless goals?

Tags: management

I had my one on one with my manager on Friday and one of the requirements was the creation of measurable goals for me that are evaluated at the end of the year. They need to be measurable so they can be compared to other developers in the company, but I have a choice of which ones.

He told me that the ones he wants his team to use are

- Pull requests per week
- Points completed per sprint

These seem like pointless metrics or highly damaging ones. I am now being punished for taking larger tasks. Am I missing something about this?

Comment: With those metrics it is disadvantageous to help your peers. You lose your time spending it on activity which is not covered by metric. With that system if team mate has a problem it is rewarding you for not helping him. This metric is also very bad in programming terms.

Comment: As this example shows, simply having "metrics" is not a magic solution. If a financial reward is made available on the basis of a fixed formula, people will find a way to game the system. But there is nothing to be gained fighting a company wide mandate - probably based on the approximately sound idea that *some* quantitative measure is better than none at all. Do your best to adapt.

Comment: Don't larger tasks weight more points in the sprint?

Comment: @PeteW well, there is more productivity, less personal annoyance and potentially even a higher position to gain by challenging rubbish policies if it's done well. How possible a good outcome is depends more on how well you can identify the key deciders and how open to feedback those people are.

Comment: Management likes concrete performance metrics because they're easy to evaluate. The difference between good and bad management is whether they realise there aren't any good metrics to measure developer performance.

Answer (score 24):

In this environment, it can be best to frame your work in terms of those goals. If you are doing larger tasks, then break them up into "pull requests" and "sprint points" so that your larger tasks actually generate a lot of "metrics". Yes, this is insanity, but so are the "goals". Either frame your work so that your manager can defend you in the manager's meetings or find another place to work.

You might not realize how vital the manager's meetings are. Those can be brutal "poker games" where managers are competing for resources, people, and their own jobs. Often, they can be more important to your employment than doing a good job for the customer. As an outside contractor, I tried hard to give my manager the information he needed for those meetings as the President was asking monthly why they were still paying for my services.

Comment: I would add, that you should score as much as necessary and as less as possible, because they likely will adjust the numbers if they are too far off.

Comment: Your answer seems to forget about the impact involving immediate peers. If OP agrees to go through these extra hoops you suggest, just to meet the demands of the manager, there is a chance that their teammates will not perceive these measures as a compliance to the manager, rather, just see them as annoying senselessness, causing unjustified friction in the teamwork, and in managing the codebase. A pull-request tends to look best when it's ready to be a pull-request. Other coders will see that.

Comment: What I suggest is that while OP might avoid further confrontation with the manager, they will see an increasing friction with immediate peers. And that can be no less of a problem.

Comment: +1. And breaking up larger tasks can actually be very helpful: it makes it easier for teammates to review it, easier for different people to pick up different pieces (or to "set it down" and pick back up much later), etc. So while these performance metrics are a bad idea, you may nonetheless find ways to make the best of them.

Comment: If my manager has to defend me with arbitrary numbers, despite me doing a good job, then personally, I'd rather get another job than work at such a shark tank.

Answer (score 11):

> These seem like pointless metrics or highly damaging ones

They are. They prove that whoever thought of them knows neither software development, nor project management. I could explain why those metrics are stupid, but I think you already know.

The common consensus is that there are no useful objective measurable metrics for software developers, mostly because a software developers whole work life is a version of "spot the pattern" and "game the system" and there is no pattern someone could invent that could not be easily gamed by your software developers. If you could come up with such a pattern, you would be in dire need of some *better* developers, because if your current developers cannot game whatever system came up, they are not very good at their job.

So, what can you do in face of obvious stupidity? Not a lot.

You *could* run with it and game the system. If you do, everybody else will, too. Nobody wants to be unfairly measured by a broken system and fall behind. This will make your day to day work life miserable. You will be working *against* you colleagues now. *Against* the other departments. Only for the metrics, despite knowing better. You will go home not with the good feeling of having done something meaningful, but with the creeping doubt if you gamed the system enough or if someone else was better in cheating today.

Or you could just not give a damn. Let them pick any metric they want. Don't look at it. Don't try to get better at it. Just do your job well and be proud of what you do. With any luck, your colleagues will do so too. If the company uses this metric to check whether you get a promotion or raise, just handle it like you would handle any other incident of this type. If you like the money you earn, stay. If you don't, find a better job.

Alternatively, if they connect this directly to bonus payments, think hard about whether you want to work for such an immature company. You are not a circus animal. Don't jump through their flaming hoops. Look for a real job in a mature company where the bosses know better.

Comment: Sometimes there are measurable, useful metrics... (I heard this anecdote in the talk "Avoiding Microservice Megadisasters".) A team was given the goal "maximize number of people who submit orders"...so they removed almost all the validation on the order page, even stuff like "this credit card number is valid". That meant that someone else had to later contact the customer with things like, "hey, you put the wrong credit card number"...but since this was the 90s, this was considered fine, and the whole thing resulted in a net profit increase and was viewed as a huge success.

Comment: This was a contrast to a metric where manager importance was based on the number of people under them--which lead to ballooning team size and unmanageable large software projects. So it's not even just developers who can't be trusted with metrics. But if you ever do come up with an actual "increase the bottom line" type metric then it can be really powerful.

Answer (score 7):

**Goals can have different goals**

In my company, there are an abundance of goals which are created because someone higher up ordered that measurable goals be created as the core piece of HR software is heavily focused on goals. So instead of starting with problems and setting goals to solve them, we are starting with the need for goals and finding problems that are nice and measurable, don’t take up too much time from other work, can be completed in the quarter, and fit with whatever goals were decided higher up the food chain. Then we only kind of do them, check them as complete, and repeat for the next quarter.

My part of one of the goals is writing a document I suspect will never be read and filing in the goal to say that it has been written. The goal exists for the sake of looking reasonable and being completed. It won’t really change or accomplish anything? Irrelevant, as that was never the goal! And it was a goal that we already had, so we were just reusing the same analysis.

At another organization, goals were entered quarterly and checked off quarterly, without the employees even knowing what their goals were. The fact that after years of doing that nobody noticed demonstrated unreservedly that they did not matter. I only learned that we had goals when I departed.

I would bet that your manager was told to create “measurable” employee metrics by someone above him and this was the result. Create a lot of pull requests for documentation and fixing grammar and spelling errors and call it a day. You can try and fight this, but the reason I don’t is that my manager is not really empowered to do much about it and it will just cause trouble for him.